# node.js execute function after 'n' async callback are executed

Tags: node.js, events, asynchronous, callback

I can't get how can I execute a callback after '*n*' async functions are executed, example:

```
var after4AsyncOperation = function(){
    //do something...
}
process.nextTick(function(){
    //do stuff
})
process.nextTick(function(){
    //do stuff
})
process.nextTick(function(){
    //do stuff
})
process.nextTick(function(){
    //do stuff
})
```

Is there a way to execute `after4AsyncOperation` after the 4 async functions without have to write the function one inside the other, ex:

```
    var after4AsyncOperation = function(){
    //do something...
}
process.nextTick(function(){
    //do stuff
    process.nextTick(function(){
        //do stuff
        process.nextTick(function(){
            //do stuff
            process.nextTick(function(){
                //do stuff
                after4Asyncoperation();
            })
        })
    })
})
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would suggest using an async library such as [Caolan's Async](https://github.com/caolan/async).  Then, you can use `async.parallel`, `async.series`, or `async.auto`.  `auto` is the most flexible, but a bit slower than the others; choosing between `parallel` and `series` would require more information on what you're trying to do - your first example would be a parallel operation, but your second example is in series.

However, if you don't want to use a library, you can write something custom.  I would do it as follows:

```
var numFuncs = 4;
var callback = function(){
  numFuncs--;
  if(numFuncs == 0) {
    after4AsyncOperation();
  }
}
var after4AsyncOperation = function(){
    //do something...
}
process.nextTick(function(){
    //do stuff
    callback();
})
process.nextTick(function(){
    //do stuff
    callback();
})
process.nextTick(function(){
    //do stuff
    callback();
})
process.nextTick(function(){
    //do stuff
    callback();
})
```

This works by counting down from the number of times we expect the callback to be called (`numFuncs`) and only calling `after4AsyncOperation` when we've been called back the right number of times.

Answer (score 3):

You can take advantage of the great [async](https://github.com/caolan/async) library that has this functionality and many other nice features. To accomplish specifically what you're looking to do, you can either use series:

https://github.com/caolan/async#series

or parallel:

https://github.com/caolan/async#parallel

The difference between the two is that series runs all the functions one after the next, while parallel runs all of them at the same time. In either case, there's a callback after they're all done which is what you seem to be trying to accomplish.